# How do I connect to a cisco switch of my network?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

I recently adquired a cisco switch 2960G24TC, I installed it on the rack of my servers and everything is ok, but how do I login the switch? it does not have an IP address, how do I login through ssh from a server from the network.

I want to administer it from the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign your switch an IP before you can manage it remotely. Use the console cable to assign an IP address to the switch and then enable ssh.

Here's the Cisco documentation w/ examples: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk583/tk617/technologies_tech_note09186a00800949e2.shtml